# Sql Server 2000 Backup

Tags: sql-server-2000

I had more database and I tried to make backup for them but they weren't worked well 
I want the best way to make backup daily

Comment: This is a serverfault question.

Comment: I guess this question has to be routed to http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serverfault and you need really to provide more information, such as what your restore SLA's are, what logging mode the database is running in, as well as whether you are permitted to change this.

Also try and define in what way the current strategy has not met your criteria, so people can understand your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Try making jobs for SQL Server Agent.